# Sub-minute streams with AWS Rekognition video streaming?

Tags: amazon-rekognition, stream-processing, cost-management

I'm trying to determine whether it is feasible from a cost perspective to use AWS Rekognition video streaming for short, scheduled streams on a camera network.

I understand that they bill $0.12/min for the service, however the docs are not clear if this is rounded to the nearest minutes *per streaming invocation* or at the end of the month.

This could result in a VERY drastic change in price when you have 1000s of cameras...

For example, if you stream 30 seconds per day for a month, are you billed for 30 minutes or 15 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

15 mins.

From [Rekognition price calculation page](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/pricing/) :

> Usage charges are applied monthly and are pro-rated for partial minutes.